# How can I change font spacing and footer formatting in a word document with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, ms-word

```
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application;
$Word.Visible = $true;
$Doc = $Word.Documents.Add();
$Section = $Doc.Sections.Item(1);
$Header = $Section.Headers.Item(1);
$Footer = $Section.Footers.Item(1);
$Footer.PageNumbers.Add($wdAlignPageNumberCenter);
$Header.Range.Text = "abcd";
$selection.Font.Name="Courier New";
$selection.Font.Size=11;
**$selection.Font.Spacing=1.0;**
$selection=$word.Selection;
```

Even though I specified my font spacing as 1.0, it is taking a default value and it seems that this is not working. Do I need to make any changes?

Also, this displays the page number in the footer column i.e. 1 or 2 or 3 like this but I want it to be like Page 1, Page 2 ,Page 3. How do I do that?

Comment: How you create `$selection`?

Comment: $selection=$word.Selection;

Comment: for me with word 2010 `$selection.Font.Spacing=1.0` works. (side note: the semicolon is not needed in powershell if the cmdlets are on different lines)

Comment: OK.........fine how to set the line spacing in script as i think  Font.Spacing object is valid  for line spacing also. Am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i have a temporary solution after some groundwork for displaying page 1,page 2 ,page 3

```
$page="`tPage";
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application;
$Word.Visible = $true;
$Doc = $Word.Documents.Add();
$Section = $Doc.Sections.Item(1);
$Footer = $Section.Footers.Item(1);
$Footer.Range.Text=$page;
$Footer.PageNumbers.Add($wdAlignPageNumberCenter);
```